# Clean architecture + sqlalchemy transaction + two model

Tags: design-patterns, fastapi

I have a question about (sqlalchemy) transaction in clean architecture (in fastapi) . All examples I've seen before are always with single model. For demonstration I developed simple fastapi app:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from sqlalchemy import sessionmaker, DeclarativeBase


app = FastAPI() 


SessionLocal = sessionmaker(...) 


class Base(DeclarativeBase) :
    pass


class Place(Base) :
    __tablename__ = "place"
    id: Mapped[int] = ... 
    name: Mapped[str]


class Coordinate(Base) :
    __tablename__ = "coordinate"
    id: Mapped[int] = .... 
    longitude: Mapped[float]
    latitude: Mapped[float]
    place_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("place.id")) 
    place: Mapped["Place"]= relationship() 


def get_session() :
    session = SessionLocal() 
    yield session
    session.close() 


longitude = float
latitude: float


class CreatPlace(BaseModel):
    name: str
    coordinates: list[longitude, latitude] 


class Repository:
    model = None

    def __init__(self, session = Depends(get_session) :
        self.session = session
        if self.model is None:
            raise ValueError("model is not specified") 

    def create(self, create_data: dict, commit: book = False) :
         instance = self.model(**create_data) 
         self.session.add(instance) 
         if commit:
             self.session.commit() 


class PlaceRepository(Repository):
    model = Place


class CoordinateRepository(Repository):
    model = Coordinate


class CreatePlaceUseCase1:
    def __init__(self, session = Depends (get_session)) :
        self.session = session
    
    def create_place(self, create_data) :
        coordinate = Coordinate(longitude=create_data.longitude, latitude=create_data.latitude) 
        place = Place(name=create_data.name, coordinate=coordinate) 
        self.session.add(place) 
        self.session.commit()


class CreatePlaceUseCase2:
    def __init__(self, session = Depends (get_session)) :
        # for transaction single session should be used
        self.session = session
        self.place_repo = PlaceRepository(session)
        self.coordinate_repo = CoordinateRepository (session) 
    
    def create_place(self, create_data):
        coordinate = self.coordinate_repo.create({"longitude": create_data.longitude, "latitude": create_data.latitude}, commit=False) 
        self.place_repo.create({"name": create_data.name, "coordinate": coordinate}, commit=True)



@app.post("/create1"):
def create_place_1(create_data: CreatePlace, use_case: CreatePlaceUseCase1 = Depends()):
    use_case.create_place(create_data) 
    return "Place created"


@app.post("/create2"):
def create_place_2(create_data: CreatePlace, use_case: CreatePlaceUseCase2 = Depends()):
    use_case.create_place(create_data) 
    return "Place created"
```

As you could there are two use cases that care about transaction. Both cases use single session. CreatePlaceUseCase1 seems to me better. And CreatePlaceUseCase2 seems verbose.

What approaches exists to deal with creating data in transaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a Clean Architecture setup where you are working with a [Python FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) application and [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) as your ORM, there are several strategies you can employ to manage transactions effectively, especially when dealing with multiple models.

You can find some of those strategies illustrated in [Kwang Soo Jeong](https://github.com/NEONKID)'s work in [`NEONKID/fastapi-ddd-example`](https://github.com/NEONKID/fastapi-ddd-example).

#### Using a Unit of Work pattern

A well-known pattern that can be applied is the Unit of Work pattern, which helps in managing transactions more easily and in a more organized manner. It encompasses all the operations against the database in a single transaction. You can find an illustration in "[Implementing the Unit of Work Pattern in Clean Architecture with .NET Core](https://medium.com/@edin.sahbaz/implementing-the-unit-of-work-pattern-in-clean-architecture-with-net-core-53efb7f9d4d)" (Jul. 2023) from [Edin Šahbaz](https://twitter.com/edinsahbaz).

```py
class UnitOfWork:
    def __init__(self, session=Depends(get_session)):
        self.session = session

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        if type is None:
            self.session.commit()
        else:
            self.session.rollback()
        self.session.close()

    def add(self, entity):
        self.session.add(entity)
```

In your use cases, you would use this `UnitOfWork` to manage transactions.

```py
class CreatePlaceUseCase1:
    def __init__(self, unit_of_work: UnitOfWork):
        self.unit_of_work = unit_of_work
    
    def create_place(self, create_data):
        with self.unit_of_work as uow:
            coordinate = Coordinate(longitude=create_data.longitude, latitude=create_data.latitude) 
            place = Place(name=create_data.name, coordinate=coordinate) 
            uow.add(place)
```

#### Utilizing SQLAlchemy Session Events

You can use [SQLAlchemy's events system](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/event.html) to manage transactions automatically at the session level:

```py
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(SessionLocal, "after_transaction_end")
def restart_savepoint(session, transaction):
    if transaction.nested and not transaction._parent.nested:
        session.expire_all()
        session.begin_nested()
```

You would use an event listener attached to the `SessionLocal` to automatically restart the save point after the transaction ends.

#### Service Layer

You can also introduce a service layer that will work with repositories to handle complex business logics and transactions. See for instance "[Our First Use Case: Flask API and Service Layer](https://www.cosmicpython.com/book/chapter_04_service_layer.html)" from [Harry Percival](https://twitter.com/hjwp).

```py
class PlaceService:
    def __init__(self, place_repo: PlaceRepository, coordinate_repo: CoordinateRepository, session=Depends(get_session)):
        self.place_repo = place_repo
        self.coordinate_repo = coordinate_repo
        self.session = session

    def create_place(self, create_data):
        try:
            coordinate = self.coordinate_repo.create({"longitude": create_data.longitude, "latitude": create_data.latitude}, commit=False)
            self.place_repo.create({"name": create_data.name, "coordinate": coordinate}, commit=False)
            self.session.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            self.session.rollback()
            raise e
```

The `PlaceService` class handles the creation of both the `Place` and `Coordinate` entities, and commits the transaction. If any exception occurs, it rolls back the transaction to maintain data integrity.

#### Comparison

- The unit of work pattern provides a clean and organized way to manage transactions
- Utilizing session events can automate transaction management at the session level.
- Introducing a service layer can help encapsulate complex business logic and transaction management into a separate layer, providing more control and flexibility.

---

[Anton Trishenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6305417/anton-trishenkov) rightly notes in the comments:

> Service shouldn't depend from a db_session.

True: `PlaceService` class and other examples provided do indeed depend directly on a `db_session` (or similar session management constructs provided by SQLAlchemy). That dependency is introduced through the initialization of service classes or use cases with a `session=Depends(get_session)` parameter, which injects a database session directly into these components.

That direct injection of `session` objects into the service layer effectively couples the business logic to the persistence mechanism (in this case, SQLAlchemy's session management).

Anton's comment points out that, according to the principles of [Clean Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) and [domain-driven design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design), the service layer should ideally be decoupled from persistence details.

In an ideal Clean Architecture setup, the service layer should operate with abstractions (like repositories or domain services) that encapsulate the persistence logic. That design allows the core application logic to remain unaffected by how data is persisted or managed, offering more flexibility and making the codebase more resilient to changes in the persistence layer.

To achieve that, you would first define abstract base classes or interfaces for your repositories. These will outline the expected operations without specifying the implementation details.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class IPlaceRepository(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def create(self, place):
        pass

class ICoordinateRepository(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def create(self, coordinate):
        pass
```

Then, implement these interfaces with concrete classes that handle the interaction with the database.

```py
class PlaceRepository(IPlaceRepository):
    def __init__(self, session):
        self.session = session

    def create(self, place):
        self.session.add(place)
        # Note: Committing is handled outside to avoid coupling
        return place

class CoordinateRepository(ICoordinateRepository):
    def __init__(self, session):
        self.session = session

    def create(self, coordinate):
        self.session.add(coordinate)
        # Note: Committing is handled outside to avoid coupling
        return coordinate
```

That way, you can refactor the service layer to depend on these repository interfaces, removing the direct dependency on the database session.

```py
class PlaceService:
    def __init__(self, place_repo: IPlaceRepository, coordinate_repo: ICoordinateRepository):
        self.place_repo = place_repo
        self.coordinate_repo = coordinate_repo

    def create_place(self, create_data):
        # Use the repository interfaces to interact with the database
        try:
            coordinate = Coordinate(longitude=create_data.longitude, latitude=create_data.latitude)
            self.coordinate_repo.create(coordinate)
            place = Place(name=create_data.name, coordinates=[coordinate])
            self.place_repo.create(place)
            # Committing is assumed to be handled at a higher level (e.g., a Unit of Work or directly in the endpoint)
        except Exception as e:
            # Assume rollback is handled at a higher level
            raise e
```

You will need to adjust your FastAPI endpoint to inject the repositories and manage the session at this level, which can include committing and rolling back transactions as necessary.

```py
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

app = FastAPI()

# Dependency to get the session
def get_session():
    session = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield session
    finally:
        session.close()

@app.post("/create")
def create_place(create_data: CreatePlace, session: Session = Depends(get_session)):
    place_repo = PlaceRepository(session)
    coordinate_repo = CoordinateRepository(session)
    place_service = PlaceService(place_repo, coordinate_repo)
    try:
        place_service.create_place(create_data)
        session.commit()
        return {"message": "Place created successfully"}
    except Exception as e:
        session.rollback()
        return {"error": str(e)}
```

Comment: Service shouldn't depend from a db_session.

Comment: @AntonTrishenkov Good point, thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, as well as proposed a refactored solution which avoids that coupling.

Comment: Hey, hey, hey. I trying to adopt DI into my current project. [This one](https://github.com/reagento/dishka/blob/develop/examples/fastapi_app.py) is very interesting and make architecture more clean.

Comment: @AntonTrishenkov Nice find! It does leverages the Dishka dependency injection (DI) library to cleanly separate concerns. It abstracts the instantiation and lifecycle management of core application components (like database gateways and interactors) into dedicated provider classes: that facilitates more modular, testable, and maintainable code by enabling easy swapping of implementations and reducing direct dependencies between components.